# How to distribute horizontal space to (2 Text-) Views on Android

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have two `TextView`s with dynamic content and thus dynamic widths I want to arrange next to each other horizontally using Android xml layouts.

If the sum of their intrinsic widths fits into the width of the container, they should each just take the space they need.

If the sum of their widths exceed the container's width, their widths should both be capped in certain ways.

Let's say our left view has a width of 400 and the right one has a width of 200. If the available space is 1000, then there should just be a space of 400 between them. But if there is only an available space of 500, then available space should be distributed:

- corresponding to the intrinsic widths: 333, 167
- or in a weighted way, for example 1 - 1: 250, 250
- or spreading the left view maintaining a minimum width of 50 of the right view: 450, 50

All of these contraints seem to be easy to implement using a horizontal `LinearLayout` or a `ConstraintLayout` but it's actually hard to me to achieve both - allowing spreading in case of sufficient space an controlled reduction in case of insufficient space.

Basically, incorporation of `WRAP_CONTENT` breaks controlled reduction and not using `WRAP_CONTENT` breaks dynamic distribution of available space, as far as I found out yet.

Could you please provide a working solution?

PS: I don't want to use any custom or third party container view.

Comment: any desired output image ?

Comment: have you seen [Google's official flexbox layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)??

Comment: @RahulKhurana  that would be a custom / third party implementation requiring an additional library, but anyway thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Concerning desired output images: I currently don't have the time to create them. Also, the problem is of a general nature. I've been annoyed by it for years. To put it different: how to put two text views with dynamic contents next to each other without unnecessarily limiting their space and making sure you at least see a portion of each.

Comment: yeah me too Oderik. But i always ended up integrating FLEXBOX layout. which has many vairations

Comment: but i think its fair to use GOOGLE library rather than depending upon other sources.